# Drawing a line in Canvas with user input

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, draw

I'm trying to draw a line in Canvas when a user gives the X and Y coordinates. This is what I have so far. I can get the canvas and the input boxes it won't draw though. I'm a newbie so any advice is appreciated.

```
<script> 
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');


var x1 = document.getElementById("x1").value;
var x2 = document.getElementById("x2").value;
var y1 = document.getElementById("y1").value;
var y2 = document.getElementById("y2").value;


function draw(){
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(x1.value,y1.value);
context.lineTo(x2.value,y2.value);
context.stroke();
}

</script>
<br><br>
<h1>Draw a Line</h1>

X-coordinate 1 <input type="text" id="start_x"><br><br>
Y-coordinate 1<input type="text" id="start_y"><br><br>
X-coordinate 2<input type="text" id="end_x"><br><br>
Y-coordinate 2<input type="text" id="end_y"><br><br>

<input type="button" value="draw" onclick="draw()">
```

Comment: please consider selecting an answer or elaborate your problem, As I answered, you have to move the statements which get input values, inside of `draw()` function, then everything will work fine!

Answer (score 1):

It's giving you undefined because you set your input id as start_x, start_y,end_x,end_y and in your js you are getting the value as x1,x2,y1,y2.

html

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>
<h1>Draw a Line</h1>
<form>
    X-coordinate 1 <input type="text" id="start_x"><br><br>
    Y-coordinate 1<input type="text" id="start_y"><br><br>
    X-coordinate 2<input type="text" id="end_x"><br><br>
    Y-coordinate 2<input type="text" id="end_y"><br><br>
    <input type="button" value="draw" onclick="draw()">
 </form>
```

js

```
 function draw(){
        var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var x1 = document.getElementById("start_x").value;
        var x2 = document.getElementById("start_y").value;
        var y1 = document.getElementById("end_x").value;
        var y2 = document.getElementById("end_y").value;
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(x1,x2);
        context.lineTo(y1,y2);
        context.stroke();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

your `draw` function is called `onclick` but the function uses the `input` `value` which was set as 'undefined' because when window loaded the value of the `input` was not defined, to resolve this you should **include your code of getting those values in the `draw` function.**

Comment: everything is undefined even the canvas

Comment: I thought it as a typo.. how can one keeps drawing using the Canvas API without defining `canvas` element?? :o ??

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your code this way;

```
<canvas width="300" height="300" id="myCanvas"></canvas><br /><br />
X-coordinate 1<input type="text" id="x1"><br><br>
Y-coordinate 1<input type="text" id="y1"><br><br>
X-coordinate 2<input type="text" id="x2"><br><br>
Y-coordinate 2<input type="text" id="y2"><br><br>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');    

function draw(){
    var x1 = document.getElementById("x1").value;
    var x2 = document.getElementById("x2").value;
    var y1 = document.getElementById("y1").value;
    var y2 = document.getElementById("y2").value;
    context.beginPath();
    context.strokeStyle="#FF0000";
    context.moveTo(x1,y1);
    context.lineTo(x2,y2);
    context.stroke();
}

</script>
<br><br>
<h1>Draw a Line</h1>

<input type="button" value="draw" onclick="draw()">
```